How to access the previous tick’s value when calc_on_every_tick=true in Pine Script?
I’m working on Pine Script where I need to update calculations on every tick. I have set calc_on_every_tick=true, but I’m struggling with accessing the previous tick’s value.
For example, I want to compare the current tick’s close value to the previous tick’s close value. Using close[1] retrieves the close value of the previous completed bar, not the previous tick.
How can I achieve this in Pine Script? Specifically, I want to determine if the current tick’s close value is higher than the previous tick’s close value. Any advice or code snippets would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

You script will be executed on every tick. Therefore you need a variable type which will keep its value during those executions on the same bar. Therefore, you need varip variables.

varip
varip (var intrabar persist) is the keyword used for the assignment
and one-time initialization of a variable or a field of a user-defined
type. It’s similar to the var keyword, but variables and fields
declared with varip retain their values between executions of the
script on the same bar.

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = true)

varip float prev_tick = na
varip float last_tick = na

prev_tick := last_tick
last_tick := close

plotchar(prev_tick, "prev_tick", "")
plotchar(last_tick, "last_tick", "")


Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! Your solution worked perfectly and helped me understand the concept better. I appreciate your time and effort in providing such a clear and concise answer.

No problem. I forgot to mention that this will only work in real-time data. On the historical bars, this cannot work because intra-bar price actions are not accessible.
